# swap two elements in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, swap

I have an array of the shape (10296, 6). I want to swap the two last elements in the subarray.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]...
```

So that 5 and 6 of each array is swapped into:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5][1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `advanced slicing` in numpy. Read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

a[:,[4, 5]] = a[:,[5, 4]]
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]])
```

Comment: oh lol, i knew i was off

Comment: hey, if it works, its fine :)